# Adding images to the right sidebar

Tags: nodes

Can anyone please tell me, using very simple terms, how to add an image to the right sidebar?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. Since a sidebar can contain many things, I have to ask it: Are you interested to add images to a block, or to something else?

Comment: you can use a view to create a block display and show any image you want. Can you elaborate of what image you wanna show ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Upload image to server using FTP or via some file manager module, like [IMCE](https://drupal.org/project/imce), [elFinder](https://drupal.org/project/elfinder), etc.
   I strongly suggest put it in somewhere inside `/sites/default/files` (sub)directory.
2. Navigate to `admin/structure/block/add` to start creating new block
3. Set empty title
4. For body field select format 'Full HTML' and enter code
   `<img src="/sites/default/files/YOUR_IMAGE_NAME.jpg" alt="IMAGE_DESCRIPTION"/>`
5. From region selection list, select 'Sidebar second' or similar
6. Below you can set the details of where block will be displayed (optional)
7. Click 'Save' button